# Importing polygon coordinates into QGIS

Tags: qgis

How would I import a `.csv` file with polygon coordinates like the sample below into QGIS?

I tried using the tool to convert geotrace to WKT and then importing the WKT via importing a delimited file but the information came in as a dbf/table.

> {"geodesic":false,"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-77.89444542198672,40.73437605298494],[-77.89417592740148,40.73437605298494],[-77.89417592740148,40.734915042155414],[-77.89444542198672,40.734915042155414],[-77.89444542198672,40.73437605298494]]]}

Comment: That looks like a Python dictionary data type and not a CSV file that could be imported into QGIS.  Can you post your whole file for us to look at because if you have a text file of dictionaries it would be easy to write a script to convert that to a proper CSV.

Comment: Which convert tool do you refer ? The valid WKT for your polygon is : `Polygon ((-77.89444542198672 40.73437605298494, -77.89417592740148 40.73437605298494, -77.89417592740148 40.73437605298494, -77.89444542198672 40.734915042155414, -77.89444542198672 40.73437605298494))`. Just paste-it in QGIS on a new polygon layer in edition mode.

Comment: Thanks J.Monticolo! This worked well.

Comment: Change the name from .csv to .geojson and drag the file into QGIS canvas.